# add input button to add input field onclick and increase number (value ) of each input field each time adding

Tags: javascript, loops, input

check this [JS Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lwyd/4/)

it solve most of the problem.
but one problem didn't solve.
when user click on "add input field" button value of field will be like 0 then 1, then 2, then 3. value will increase on each click.

```
<input type="text" value="0" />
<input type="text" value="1" />
<input type="text" value="2" />
<input type="text" value="4" />
```

thanks

Comment: Presuming you have a reference to the input, then `input.value = ++input.value;`.

Comment: Please post your code here, not just a link to a site.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `ijk` variable outside the click handler and then inside the click handler increase the variable. Like this...

```
var ijk = 0;

$('#addInputs').click(function () {

    var zzz = '<input type="text" value="'+ ijk +'" />';
    $('#inputList').append(zzz);
    ijk++;
});
```

Here's a working [JS Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lwyd/5/)

Comment: excellent. this is what i searching for. thanks for the reply. :)